# how to fix the Badrequest error?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger

The following is the log of the orderer.

```
Attaching to orderer.asset.com, peer0.legaldept.asset.com, peer0.sellerbank.asset.com, peer0.buyerbank.asset.com, peer0.registration.asset.com, cli
orderer.asset.com               | 2018-04-09 13:12:22.351 UTC orderer/common/server] prettyPrintStruct -> INFO 001 Orderer config values:
orderer.asset.com               |       General.LedgerType = "file"
orderer.asset.com               |       General.ListenAddress = "0.0.0.0"
orderer.asset.com               |       General.ListenPort = 7050
orderer.asset.com               |       General.TLS.Enabled = true
orderer.asset.com               |       General.TLS.PrivateKey = "/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.key"
orderer.asset.com               |       General.TLS.Certificate = "/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.crt"
orderer.asset.com               |       General.TLS.RootCAs = [/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/ca.crt]
orderer.asset.com               |       General.TLS.ClientAuthRequired = false
orderer.asset.com               |       General.TLS.ClientRootCAs = []
orderer.asset.com               |       General.Keepalive.ServerMinInterval = 1m0s
orderer.asset.com               |       General.Keepalive.ServerInterval = 2h0m0s
orderer.asset.com               |       General.Keepalive.ServerTimeout = 20s
orderer.asset.com               |       General.GenesisMethod = "file"
orderer.asset.com               |       General.GenesisProfile = "SampleInsecureSolo"
orderer.asset.com               |       General.SystemChannel = "testchainid"
orderer.asset.com               |       General.GenesisFile = "/var/hyperledger/orderer/orderer.genesis.block"
orderer.asset.com               |       General.Profile.Enabled = false
orderer.asset.com               |       General.Profile.Address = "0.0.0.0:6060"
orderer.asset.com               |       General.LogLevel = "INFO"
orderer.asset.com               |       General.LogFormat = "%{color}%{time:2006-01-02 15:04:05.000 MST} [%{module}] %{shortfunc} -> %{level:.4s} %{id:03x}%{color:reset} %{message}"
orderer.asset.com               |       General.LocalMSPDir = "/var/hyperledger/orderer/msp"
orderer.asset.com               |       General.LocalMSPID = "OrdererMSP"
orderer.asset.com               |       General.BCCSP.ProviderName = "SW"
orderer.asset.com               |       General.BCCSP.SwOpts.SecLevel = 256
orderer.asset.com               |       General.BCCSP.SwOpts.HashFamily = "SHA2"
orderer.asset.com               |       General.BCCSP.SwOpts.Ephemeral = false
orderer.asset.com               |       General.BCCSP.SwOpts.FileKeystore.KeyStorePath = "/var/hyperledger/orderer/msp/keystore"
orderer.asset.com               |       General.BCCSP.SwOpts.DummyKeystore =
orderer.asset.com               |       General.BCCSP.PluginOpts =
orderer.asset.com               |       General.BCCSP.Pkcs11Opts =
orderer.asset.com               |       General.Authentication.TimeWindow = 15m0s
orderer.asset.com               |       FileLedger.Location = "/var/hyperledger/production/orderer"
orderer.asset.com               |       FileLedger.Prefix = "hyperledger-fabric-ordererledger"
orderer.asset.com               |       RAMLedger.HistorySize = 1000
orderer.asset.com               |       Kafka.Retry.ShortInterval = 5s
orderer.asset.com               |       Kafka.Retry.ShortTotal = 10m0s
orderer.asset.com               |       Kafka.Retry.LongInterval = 5m0s
orderer.asset.com               |       Kafka.Retry.LongTotal = 12h0m0s
orderer.asset.com               |       Kafka.Retry.NetworkTimeouts.DialTimeout = 10s
orderer.asset.com               |       Kafka.Retry.NetworkTimeouts.ReadTimeout = 10s
orderer.asset.com               |       Kafka.Retry.NetworkTimeouts.WriteTimeout = 10s
orderer.asset.com               |       Kafka.Retry.Metadata.RetryMax = 3
orderer.asset.com               |       Kafka.Retry.Metadata.RetryBackoff = 250ms
orderer.asset.com               |       Kafka.Retry.Producer.RetryMax = 3
orderer.asset.com               |       Kafka.Retry.Producer.RetryBackoff = 100ms
orderer.asset.com               |       Kafka.Retry.Consumer.RetryBackoff = 2s
orderer.asset.com               |       Kafka.Verbose = false
orderer.asset.com               |       Kafka.Version = 0.10.2.0
orderer.asset.com               |       Kafka.TLS.Enabled = false
orderer.asset.com               |       Kafka.TLS.PrivateKey = ""
orderer.asset.com               |       Kafka.TLS.Certificate = ""
orderer.asset.com               |       Kafka.TLS.RootCAs = []
orderer.asset.com               |       Kafka.TLS.ClientAuthRequired = false
orderer.asset.com               |       Kafka.TLS.ClientRootCAs = []
orderer.asset.com               |       Debug.BroadcastTraceDir = ""
orderer.asset.com               |       Debug.DeliverTraceDir = ""
orderer.asset.com               | 2018-04-09 13:12:22.351 UTC [orderer/common/server] initializeServerConfig -> INFO 002 Starting orderer with TLS enabled
orderer.asset.com               | 2018-04-09 13:12:22.362 UTC [orderer/common/server] initializeMultichannelRegistrar -> INFO 003 Not bootstrapping because of existing chains
orderer.asset.com               | 2018-04-09 13:12:22.403 UTC [orderer/commmon/multichannel] NewRegistrar -> INFO 004 Starting system channel 'testchainid' with genesis block hash 484aaf17fd08e1e01a167b04d137c83a1508f3f7e9b57a7b7a8a4749f93688bc and orderer type solo
orderer.asset.com               | 2018-04-09 13:12:22.407 UTC [orderer/common/server] Start -> INFO 005 Starting orderer:
orderer.asset.com               |  Version: 1.1.0
orderer.asset.com               |  Go version: go1.9.2
orderer.asset.com               |  OS/Arch: linux/amd64
orderer.asset.com               |  Experimental features: false
orderer.asset.com               | 2018-04-09 13:12:22.407 UTC [orderer/common/server] Start -> INFO 006 Beginning to serve requests
```

when i tried to create channel getting

> Error: got unexpected status: BAD_REQUEST -- error authorizing update: error validating DeltaSet: policy for [Group]  /Channel/Application not satisfied: Failed to reach implicit threshold of 1 sub-policies, required 1 remaining

Comment: Can you add the request you were trying to make to create the channel?